# Android studio kotlin files show as R class from different packages and XML files

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

This is not my project but the code runs fine. Some kotlin files show up as either R class from some random package or as XML files and have different icons. Files that show correctly have errors like Unresolved reference pointing to the files that don't show correctly  but it still compiles and runs.

Android studio 3.2.1

Gradle 4.6

Kotlin plugin 1.2.51 and 1.2.71
[image]

Comment: Have you tried manually `import` that package containing the project's R class in that Kotlin file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fix to this is to open and save the file in question with a text editor like sublime text or notepad. I'm not sure if this is a bug with android studio or what but I can't submit a bug either way since I doubt this is reproducible. If anyone else is experiencing this, I hope this workaround works for you and thanks for everyone who helped, have a good day.

Answer (score 0):

Try these:

1. build -> clean project, build project
2. file -> sync project with Gradle files
3. file -> invalidate and restart